# Error bars for mean of x divided by mean of y

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have some data about fluorescence from different plants treated with different chemicals that make them fluoresce. In each treatment n=2, if that matters.

I am using a column graph to show the mean intensity of each treatment, *divided by the control group*.

```
        Intensity      Mean         SD
Treatment 1 6904890    6877987.5    26902.5
            6851085     
Treatment 2 256275     298732.5     42457.5
            341190      
Treatment 8 3692910    3671107.5    21802.5
            3649305     
Treatment 9 1693710    1599232.5    94477.5
            1504755
```

Now I want to plot four columns:

```
(Treatment1/Treatment1)
(Treatment2/Treatment1)
(Treatment3/Treatment1)
(Treatment4/Treatment1)
```

where treatment1 is my control so I am "normalizing" or making my data relative to its value.

My question is what do I properly do with the error bars to show the most applicable measure of variance?

As simple as this question sounds, I can't find a straight forward answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. You seem to be asking for an appropriate statistical method to estimate uncertainty. You'd probably have to have some idea of the covariances to properly account for that in a ratio. You should ask such questions over at [stats.se] where questions about statistical matters are on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Take variance of the sample, divide by root N, then divide again by the value of treatment 1 to get your error.
However with N as low as 2 is doubtful that the error bars actually mean anything.